# How do you remove the decimal in a column of ICD codes?

Tags: r

I am sure this is simple, but I am not finding an answer, so anything helps! I have a variable for ICD code and the decimals are still in the codes. Using R, how do I remove the decimal so that this observation, 'O99.013', would look like this 'O99013' ? (NOTE: There are letters in the ICD codes, so it is not being treated like an integer)

Comment: thanks @camille, I looked for the duplicates but couldn't find them

Answer (score 1):

Removing dots is a little bit tricky because they're treated as special characters in regular expressions.

```r
gsub("\\.", "", mydata$ICD_code)
```

or

```r
gsub(".", "", mydata$ICD_code, fixed = TRUE)
```

or

```r
gsub("[.]", "", mydata$ICD_code)
```

(`.` is not treated as a special character when it's included in a set of characters with `[]`)

or the equivalent with `stringr::str_remove()`